# Sitecore Publishing: Sometimes not publishing Datasource Changes

Tags: publishing-service

We've found another interesting possible issue with the Publishing Service (v2.0).
When we change the Datasource for a rendering in an item's presentation details (and nothing else), then publish that item, the change sometimes doesn't make it to the Web database.

To reproduce the issue we had to change the datasource to different things and publish four or five times, but our content authors have reported it happening on the first change.

If we then publish the item With Subitems it seems to push out the datasource consistently, but it's of course possible that that's coincidence.

Here's what I've found in the log. The first is when it did work, and the second when it didn't. On the second it didn't do the "Added 1 steps to manifest", so it seems like it just sometimes doesn't notice the change.

Have any of you seen something like this?

```
2017-05-08 18:41:05.650 -04:00 [Information] New Job queued : aa7213aa-567f-4aa0-9f8c-204eddff717c - Targets: "Internet"
2017-05-08 18:41:05.666 -04:00 [Information] Start building source index
2017-05-08 18:41:07.798 -04:00 [Information] Source index built successfully
2017-05-08 18:41:07.954 -04:00 [Information] Executing Publish : 
Source: "master", 
Targets: ["Internet"], 
Start Item: c011c230-1f5b-401e-9974-7a23ca97d7a6, 
Languages: ["en"], 
Process Descendants: False, 
Process Related Items: True

2017-05-08 18:41:08.017 -04:00 [Information] Created manifest d786f616-6fb3-4596-90af-23e8b41032b7, for target 8e080626-ddc3-4ef4-a1d1-f0be4a200254
2017-05-08 18:41:08.017 -04:00 [Information] Starting the manifest calculation for target : "Internet" (Id : 8e080626-ddc3-4ef4-a1d1-f0be4a200254)
2017-05-08 18:41:08.033 -04:00 [Information] Start building item index for target: 8e080626-ddc3-4ef4-a1d1-f0be4a200254
2017-05-08 18:41:15.544 -04:00 [Information] Item index built successfully for target: 8e080626-ddc3-4ef4-a1d1-f0be4a200254
2017-05-08 18:41:16.091 -04:00 [Information] Added 1 steps to manifest: d786f616-6fb3-4596-90af-23e8b41032b7.
2017-05-08 18:41:16.091 -04:00 [Information] Starting to promote the manifests to all targets..
2017-05-08 18:41:16.091 -04:00 [Information] Starting to promote Target : "Internet", Manifest : d786f616-6fb3-4596-90af-23e8b41032b7.
2017-05-08 18:41:16.123 -04:00 [Information] Promote completed successfully -> Target : "Internet", Manifest : d786f616-6fb3-4596-90af-23e8b41032b7.
2017-05-08 18:41:16.138 -04:00 [Information] Job Result: aa7213aa-567f-4aa0-9f8c-204eddff717c - "Complete" - "OK". Duration: 00:00:10.4882483
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-05-08 18:41:47.818 -04:00 [Information] New Job queued : e1583126-756c-46ef-adc4-fa109c0447cf - Targets: "Internet"
2017-05-08 18:41:47.849 -04:00 [Information] Start building source index
2017-05-08 18:41:49.584 -04:00 [Information] Source index built successfully
2017-05-08 18:41:49.740 -04:00 [Information] Executing Publish : 
Source: "master", 
Targets: ["Internet"], 
Start Item: c011c230-1f5b-401e-9974-7a23ca97d7a6, 
Languages: [], 
Process Descendants: False, 
Process Related Items: True

2017-05-08 18:41:49.896 -04:00 [Information] Created manifest 5fe6669e-32ed-4fd1-a5e5-a27079867d52, for target 8e080626-ddc3-4ef4-a1d1-f0be4a200254
2017-05-08 18:41:49.896 -04:00 [Information] Starting the manifest calculation for target : "Internet" (Id : 8e080626-ddc3-4ef4-a1d1-f0be4a200254)
2017-05-08 18:41:49.912 -04:00 [Information] Start building item index for target: 8e080626-ddc3-4ef4-a1d1-f0be4a200254
2017-05-08 18:41:57.747 -04:00 [Information] Item index built successfully for target: 8e080626-ddc3-4ef4-a1d1-f0be4a200254
2017-05-08 18:41:58.012 -04:00 [Information] Starting to promote the manifests to all targets..
2017-05-08 18:41:58.028 -04:00 [Information] Starting to promote Target : "Internet", Manifest : 5fe6669e-32ed-4fd1-a5e5-a27079867d52.
2017-05-08 18:41:58.028 -04:00 [Information] Promote completed successfully -> Target : "Internet", Manifest : 5fe6669e-32ed-4fd1-a5e5-a27079867d52.
2017-05-08 18:41:58.028 -04:00 [Information] Job Result: e1583126-756c-46ef-adc4-fa109c0447cf - "Complete" - "OK". Duration: 00:00:10.1941100
```

Comment: are you publishing selecting the related items?

Comment: Yes, we have the Publish Related Items box checked in all of these cases.

Comment: have you checked for workflow and it not being ready for publish?

Comment: We're currently not using workflows

Comment: Can you run in debug mode ? (`--environment development`) 

When you make the change to the datasource you should see the `publishOperation` being saved in the console (this is showing that it registered the save correctly.. this operation will be used in the next publish to track what has changed). Id be interested to see in the cases when it doesnt work if the `publishOperation` is triggered.

Comment: For example :

`[15:00:52 DBG] 1 PublisherOperations received.

[15:00:52 DBG]    ...110d559f-dea5-42ea-9c1c-8a5df7e70ef9 en 1 Variant Saved`

Comment: Alright this is a little weird. When I try this on my local it works as expected. When I do it on a remote environment that's more like our production (separate CD and CM, publishing service is on the CM box) it never reports PublishingOperations received, but it does show the actual publish in the console, and the changed items do show up as expected in Web.

Comment: Hmm.. odd. I would check the connection to the publishing service (and that it has a trailing slash) on those other machines. If its being blocked or filtered. If it can't save this operation (or the operation cant get to the service) then the publish will not do anything (as it will think it has nothing to do)

Comment: It does definitely publish the changed items successfully so it does seem like it's doing everything correctly, it's just not reporting the changes to the console. It is still possible that it's a configuration issue though, I'll keep looking, but at first glance everything seems right.

Comment: @Slee did you solved your problem? Its possible that LinkDatabase is set to core in Publishing Service, and in your scaled environment LinkDatabase is set to web - that's why in your local works just fine. Can you check ?